# RecyclerView scroll to top before start of activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, start-activity

I am using below lib for shimmer recycleView.

https://github.com/sharish/ShimmerRecyclerView

below is my recycleview

```
<com.cooltechworks.views.shimmer.ShimmerRecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                android:id="@+id/shimmer_recycler_view"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/eight_dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/eight_dp"
                                android:clipToPadding="false"
                                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                                app:shimmer_demo_angle="30"
                                app:shimmer_demo_child_count="6"
                                app:shimmer_demo_layout="@layout/schedule_item_row_placeholder_latest"
                                app:shimmer_demo_mask_width="0.2"
                                app:shimmer_demo_shimmer_color="@color/shimmer_color"
                                app:shimmer_demo_view_holder_item_background="@drawable/bg_card" />
```

When you click on item(any row) I am starting detail activity below is the code,

```
myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity,ListDetailActivity.class);
                    mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
```

Before start of detail activity ShimmerRecyclerView  scrolls to top and start detail activity.

Why it is happening?How can I control?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: First change height to _wrap_content_ and remove                             _android:scrollbars="vertical"_ because already you set vertical layout manager.

Comment: @Piyush I did but no use, It just remove scrollbars indicator( if more elements are there).

Comment: Have you used _scrollToPosition_ for recyclerview anywhere?

Comment: @Piyush no I have not added scrollToPosition